# Port not changing in Sharepoint Configuration wizard setup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to change the default random port but its still taking random port, what could be the issue, I had tried mulitple times but no luck.

[image]

Comment: what you mean by its not getting? after checking the box(specify the port) and entering the new port number (2000) and click next.what you get on the next page?

Comment: Its always taking random port even if I specify port.

Comment: Can u share screen shot after entering port 2300, click next (this screenshot) and last summary page screen

Comment: I tried with 2300, I got error log with different port:
A SocketException was thrown with SocketError ConnectionRefused
                    Connect has been refused for port 32457, so we will consider this a free port
                  Have not found a free port yet.  Number of tries is 1.  Min port we will try is 1024, Max port we will try is 49151
                   Adding port 32457 to the exclusion list so it is not chosen again during this run

Comment: It always taking random port

Comment: Is firewall enabled on the server? Also try commandline psconfig